How to reduce the height of the graph itself react-native-chart-kit?
I use react-native-chart-kit - LineChart. I want to reduce the height of the graph itself. If I set the value 'height' too small, will be cut off x-axis bottom Labels. I need to reduce the height of the field with the graph itself, without cropping - need to compress the graph height.
